# Does a factorization of a modular fusion category imply some "factorization" of TFTs?

Tags: topological-quantum-field-theory, modular-tensor-categories

Mueger showed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0201017) that if $C$ is a modular fusion category and $D$ is a modular fusion subcategory of $C$, then $C$ is equivalent to $D \boxtimes M_C(D)$ as ribbon categories, where $M_C(D)$ is the *Mueger centralizer* of $D$ in $C$ (which is incidentally also modular).

Does this factorization of $C$ somehow impart a factorization of e.g. the Reshetikhin-Turaev TFT $\mathcal{Z}^{RT}_{C}$ built from $C$?
Or maybe the other way around, is knowing the TFTs $\mathcal{Z}^{RT}_{D}$ and
$\mathcal{Z}^{RT}_{M_C(D)}$ enough to (somehow) obtain $\mathcal{Z}^{RT}_C$?

Comment: Yes, a factorization of modular categories corresponds to a factorization of RT TQFTs.